# How to hide sensitive information in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api

I am connecting my website to several APIs like Firebase and Pusher.
However, all of the credentials written within javascript are exposed to public.
Is it sensitive?
What is the good practice in dealing with this?

Below are some example of my API.

Firebase

```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "MyAPIKey",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "myapp",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "12345678",
    appId: "1:12345678:web:e812345678b",
    measurementId: "G-0001"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Pusher

```
    var pusher = new Pusher('XXXXX', {
        encrypted: false,
        cluster: 'mt1',
        wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
        wsPort: 6001,
    });

    var user_id = 11;
   
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('msg' + user_id);
    
    channel.bind('App\\Events\\Messaging', function(data) {
      console.log(data.message);
    });
```

Take a look at the source Linode dashboard.
How did the accomplished this?
The exposed code is so little.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/new-relic.js"></script><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/assets/logo-192-apple.png"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/fonts/fonts.css"/><title>Linode Manager</title></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="session-iframe"></div><div id="root"></div><script src="/static/js/main.339b6f48.js"></script></body><script src="https://static.ada.support/embed.be6a6728.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script><script>window.setTimeout(()=>{var t=document.getElementsByClassName("ada-iframe")[0];t&&t.setAttribute("title","Ada Support Chat Bot")},2e3)</script></html>
```

Comment: nope..that is how to deal with your own code. This issue dealing with others APIs. Its beyond our control.

Comment: The answer is, you can't. Web pages are open for the browser to read any information. This is why OAuth exists

Comment: Since this is a web page and not node, this content is delivered to every browser. Anyone can dissect and grab this information to use against you. You can keep it encoded so it isnt queryable with ctrl+f.  That said, it only obfuscates the data.   Since you have the expectation that the data is going to be on N bowsers, your server is ok with N connections.  Cutting this down would like be a process of having the app verify with a server handshake to receive creds which can then be changed on the fly from the aspect of the server if something is compromised.